# Should I split long string for coding style vs lower performance of concatenating strings Java

Tags: string, performance, split, coding-style, concatenation

Based on the google style doc (https://google.github.io/styleguide/javaguide.html), it is recommended to limit a line to at most 100 column long. However, I have to declare some strings as description which can be 300 characters long. In order to fit in 100 characters each line, The string needs to be split into

`setDescription("abcxjkfdjskahlkjfkldas...100 fjdskal;fjds ...100 jdfkds...100")`

to

`setDescription("abcxjkfdjskahlkjfkldas...100" + "fjdskal;fjds ...100" + "jdfkds...100")`

With this will slow down the performance of concatenating the string. With StringBuilder, I have to create a new object and append each string, just for the satisfying the style. There seems to be a tradeoff. Could someone help to explain what is a better approach?